# SSIS - Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl, ssis-2008

I have installed Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable from below link. But I do not understand What do they really mean in the highlighted point in Additional Information section from the given link.

Since SSIS package running on local machines but not on UAT and SIT Servers after installation. Any suggestion Please.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

*"The Office System Drivers are only supported under certain scenarios, including:*

*- Desktop applications which read from and write to various files formats -including Microsoft Office Access, Microsoft Office Excel and text files.*

*- To transfer data between supported file formats and a database repository, such as SQL Server. For example, to transfer data from an Excel workbook into SQL Server using the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard or SQL Server Integration Services (**provided the SSIS jobs run in the context of a logged-on user with a valid HKEY_CURRENT_USER registry hive**)."*

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for.

Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable contains a set of components that allows the user to connect to microsoft office files (such as Excel and Access) even if microsoft office is not installed or you have an older office version (i.e. office 2003).

You can benefit from these components only in 2 cases:

- If you are developing an application that connect with office files (excel, access, ...) using libraries such as `System.Data.Oledb` (or maybe `Office.Interop` *(not sure)*)
- If you are using SQL Server Import and Export Wizard or SQL Server Integration Services *(if Microsoft Office and Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable are not installed) you cannot connect to microsoft excel and access using SSIS.)*

Comment: What is the difference between Microsoft Access redistributable and runtime? - asked separately here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68919765/what-is-the-difference-between-redistributable-and-runtime

Answer (score 1):

I will add just some basic overview: the Access Runtime (redistributable) is fully able to operate linking to SQL DB, Excel, etc.

But it has no design features - so one cannot alter or set up any of these links.

One must set up links using full licensed Access.  The it will run fine in the runtime.

Implied within this construct is that of course the link path of the runtime machines (to the linked file) must be the same as the full license development machine.  In most LAN environments that are properly constructed, and the Access development occurs on the same LAN as the Access users, this is fine because the back end server is a common location to all i.e. something like :   R:\MainFolder\database

CahabaData.com