# What is the difference between microsoft access redistributable and runtime?

Tags: excel, ms-access, ssis, runtime, redistributable

To be able to use Excel via SSIS workflow, I need to install the appropriate plugin. What is the difference between redistributable and runtime?

Example:

- [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=13255)
- [Microsoft Access 2010 Runtime](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=10910)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Access Runtime

Based on the [Microsoft Access 2010 Runtime download page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=10910):

> The Microsoft Access 2010 Runtime **enables you to distribute Access 2010 applications to users who do not have the full version of Access 2010 installed on their computers**.

This package is used to deploy Microsoft Access applications. Lots of details can be found in [the following article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/deploy-an-access-application-7bb4f2ba-30ee-458c-a673-102dc34bf14f). *(Check the "Understand and download the Access Runtime" section)*

In that documentation they mentioned that:

> To deploy Access applications **that can run without an installation of Access on a user's computer, you can distribute them along with the Access Runtime**, which is available for free from the Microsoft Download Center. When you open an Access database by using the Access Runtime, the database opens in runtime mode.

> **Runtime mode is an Access operating mode in which certain Access features are not available by default**. Some of these unavailable features can be made available in runtime mode, however.

### Database Engine Redistributable

On the [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable download page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=13255) they mentioned that:

> This download will install a set of components that can be used to facilitate the transfer of data between 2010 Microsoft Office System files and non-Microsoft Office applications.

> This download will install a set of components that facilitate the transfer of data between existing Microsoft Office files such as Microsoft Office Access 2010 (*.mdb and *.accdb) files and Microsoft Office Excel 2010 (*.xls, *.xlsx, and *.xlsb) files to other data sources such as Microsoft SQL Server. Connectivity to existing text files is also supported. **ODBC and OLEDB drivers are installed for application developers to use in developing their applications with connectivity to Office file formats**.

### Answering your question

Back to your question, **the Microsoft Access Database Engine Redistributable is the one that you need to install** since it contains the needed OLE DB and ODBC drivers for Microsoft Access and Excel.